# How to make this submenu 100% width?

Tags: html, css

here's a fantastics CSS menu:

`http://www.devinrolsen.com/wp-content/themes/dolsen/demos/css/infinite-sub-menu/`

the only problem is its 200px widthed... if I change it to 100% it doesnt work... all width of submenus are different in IE.

Comment: show us your code, ideally in a [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: click on the link, nothing changed

Comment: then show us [`what you tried`](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: theres a line: "li:hover > .nav { display:block; position:absolute; width:200px; top:-2px; left:50%; z-index:1000; border:1px #000 solid; } " and "WIDTH:200px" I changed it to 100% and it didnt work! Thats the only thing I tried...

Comment: what happens to the third-level submenu if the second-level submenu has 100% width already?

Answer (score 1):

it is working see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zbZfn/1/).   i have checked with firefox and IE8

Comment: thats right, but when the length of fields are different, you can see the fail

Comment: ty. I forgot to tell that I need the same lengths. The lengtest item should say all the length. No line breaks, in other words

Comment: rt2800, then all the submenus disappears

Comment: as @rt2800 suggested,just change display:block to display:table in li:hover>.nav

Comment: @Pranav, it firefox this works but in IE all submenus are gone

Comment: hm yes working now, the compatibility mode was turned ON :D maybe a solution for "IE 8 compatibility mode" or I dont need to deal with it? (I dont care IE6)